# How to update a DataGridView in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have to update a `DataGridView` with products. Those products are grouped by categories. For every category I have made a `Panel`. When that `Panel` is clicked, I would like to display a list of `Panel`s, which contain products from the clicked `Panel`. Also, when I click a `Panel` from the list I would like it to be inserted in the `DataGridView`. Is this scenario possible?

Screenshot: [image]

Description for the screenshot:

-Categories are in the top-left side.

-When a category is pressed , a list of Database records are displayed in the left side.

-When a record is pressed then it binds to datagridview.

Comment: Which part of the scenario do you need help?  Just adding to the grid?  Additionally, how are you loading your data into the DataGridView?  Are you binding?

Comment: Yes, I'm binding ... The part where i click a category panel and where the products for that category should be displayed.

Comment: What are you planning to display in the Products panel?  Could this be a list or a grid?

Comment: A list of buttons or panels! And the products are going to be bind when the button or the panel is pressed.

Comment: i just can't figure it out ... i'm a beginner in C# and i need help !

Comment: @EmilDumbazu It's ok to be a beginner, everyone starts like this. But you should take care of posting precisely your problem. SO users generally dont accept questions like "I want this and this, do that for me" style of questions. You will learn it with time here. Welcome to SO ;)

Comment: @EmilDumbazu //After a few hours after i posted the question i kinda did the same thing as you, but mines does not not working properly.// Do not just state that it didnt work. Tell us where it went wrong and what exactly. Use visual studio to debug your code and see the values of variables and fields at important instants. If you do not know how to do all that, tell us that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand how the GUI would be. A screenshot will help us better. Not sure if clicking on a panel is an ideal way of letting users open up something. Hope panels have borders.

Supposing each panel has its category object tagged to it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Category> lstCategory = Manager.GetCategories();

    int i = 5, j = 5;
    foreach (Category cat in lstCategory)
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = cat.Name;
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.Tag = cat;
        panel.Controls.Add(label);
        //if you already have panel created for categories, then start from here..
        panel.Click += ((s, r) =>
        {
            List<Product> lstProduct = Manager.GetProducts((Category)panel.Tag);

            int x = 5, y = 5;
            foreach (Product product in lstProduct)
            {
                var pnl = new Panel();
                pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                pnl.Size = new Size(15, 15);
                pnl.Location = new Point(20 + x, 20 + y); //position it properly.
                this.Controls.Add(pnl);
                pnl.Tag = product;
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = product.Name;
                pnl.Controls.Add(lbl);
                pnl.Click += ((p, q) =>
                {
                   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(//according to pnl.Tag values

                });
            }
        });

        panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        panel.Size = new Size(15, 15);
        panel.Location = new Point(20 + i, 20 + j); //position it properly.
        this.Controls.Add(panel);

    }
}
```

You can refactor the codes that create the panels to one method by passing necessary things as parameters if you want.